# keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.NotFound: The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404)

Tags: python-2.7, openstack-nova, novaclient

I am trying to list nova flavors list.

```
from keystoneclient.auth.identity import v3
from keystoneclient import session
from keystoneclient.v3 import client
from novaclient import client



auth = v3.Password(auth_url="https://api-soltes2:5000/v3.0",
                   username="i-soltest",
                   password="i-soltest",
                   project_id='d5eef1aae54742e787d0653eea57254b',
                   user_domain_id="853ee41e624e4a70962b225bd1dbda6e     ")
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
#keystone = client.Client(version='2.0',session=sess)
#keystone.project.list()

nova = client.Client(2.1, session=sess)
nova.flavors.list()
```